# ServiceStack: How to see if the handler for the current request requires authentication

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I have a webservice using the old API. Almost all of my service handlers requires authentication and I therefore use the Authenticate attribute on the service level.

All my services implement a custom base service, which use OnBeforeExecute to populate some authentication related properties.

Is there a fast way to see if the handler for the current request requires authentication in the OnBeforeExecute method?

I would prefer not having to look through the attributes using reflection as I understand this to be a fairly slow operation. I also expect that the ServiceStack system already has this information somewhere in its belly :)

---

**What I ended up doing**:

Since my project has services where I use the ApplyTo argument of Authenticate to disable the auth requirement for some handlers, I ended up with the following.

```
protected override void OnBeforeExecute(TRequestDto request)
{
    base.OnBeforeExecute(request);

    var attr = FilterAttributeCache.GetRequestFilterAttributes(request.GetType()).OfType<AuthenticateAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (attr != null)
    {
        ApplyTo reqmethod = base.Request.HttpMethodAsApplyTo();
        if ((attr.ApplyTo & reqmethod) == reqmethod)
        {
            //
            // do stuff that should only be done when 
            // the handler requires authentication
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about the [Authentication](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/AuthenticateAttribute.cs) request filter attribute, other than it has the [lowest priority](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/RequestFilterAttribute.cs) so it's executed first.

ServiceStack does maintain a [FilterAttributeCache](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/Utils/FilterAttributeCache.cs) of all attributes a Request DTO has, so you can use this API to determine if the AuthenticateAttribute is defined for a particular service, e.g:

```
var hasAuth = FilterAttributeCache.GetRequestFilterAttributes(request.GetType())
   .OfType<AuthenticateAttribute>().FirstOrDefault() != null;
```

Comment: Thank you Mythz :) I was certain there would some clever way built-in